# Can we block the file share option in One Drive?

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive

Customer Requirement :

Customer want to use one drive with more security perspective do not share the files to any internal organization as well Extern users as well. Due to security reason.

Can we achieve on this?

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

External sharing can easily be blocked in for all one drive sites or selected one drive sites in the SharePoint admin center. Full instructions for that are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off). As far as I know, there is no mechanism to block internal sharing.

Answer (score 0):

1.For internal organization, I suggest you use permission to control file share.

2.For external users, set external sharing as Only people in your organization.

[image]